# como funciona este codigo de subqueries sql?

Tags: sql

estoy practicando con subqueries de un pagina llamada galaxql y en el ejercicio 11 me plantean esto:

Hilight the star (or stars) which has the planet with the highest orbit distance in the galaxy. Remember to clear the old hilights before beginning

```sql
INSERT INTO hilight 
SELECT stars.starid 
FROM stars, planets, 
(SELECT MAX(orbitdistance) AS mo FROM planets) 
WHERE planets.orbitdistance = mo 
AND planets.starid = stars.starid;
```

(esta es la manera de resolverlo)
pero no entiendo el por que agarra con el from mas de una tabla y por que no usa los joins

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta usando una forma vieja de joins, implicitos, eso quiere decir que si hace los joins, a traves del where. Es lo mismo. Ahora, porque usa 3 tablas, no lo se, habria que ver los modelos y que datos quiere poner en cada tabla...

Answer (score 0):

La consulta usa una sintaxis antigua que lista todas las tablas y agrega las condiciones para unirlas en la clausula `WHERE`. En realidad, la subconsulta no debería de ser tratada como una tabla derivada sino como un valor escalar que se pueda usar directamente en el WHERE. Una refactorización de la consulta podría quedar así:

```
INSERT INTO hilight 
SELECT stars.starid 
FROM stars AS s
JOIN planets AS p ON p.starid = s.starid
JOIN (SELECT MAX(orbitdistance) AS mo FROM planets) AS m ON p.orbitdistance = mo;
```

Aunque realmente preferiría quitar el segundo JOIN.

```
INSERT INTO hilight 
SELECT stars.starid 
FROM stars AS s
JOIN planets AS p ON p.starid = s.starid
WHERE p.orbitdistance = (SELECT MAX(orbitdistance) FROM planets);
```

Comment: Hola gracias, a que te refieres exactamente con esto 'En realidad, la subconsulta no debería de ser tratada como una tabla derivada sino como un valor escalar que se pueda usar directamente en el WHERE'

Comment: Me refiero a dejarlo como en el segundo ejemplo.